# Pages manipulation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I am building a website in which I have added a function to change the theme. However, the issue is that I have many pages in my websites and, when I move to the next page, it resets the default value. I want to select the theme only once and then keep it in my whole website.

Comment: save user preferences in localstorage and read from there.

Comment: And here is a [link to localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to help get you started

Comment: I would be recommended to provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable code example in order to help others to detect the possible errors or suggest new solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` to persist data. It will be accessible from each page of your site.

This is a barebones example, and I urge you to do more research on `localStorage`, such as how to determine whether there is enough space to store data. And also do some checks to determine whether the data you're looking for exists.

Source: https://snippets.cacher.io/snippet/fdc6f8a598f1395092e7

Sample:

Page 1:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="paragraph">Hello</p>
        <p id="loadedText"></p>
        <button onclick="load();">Load</button>
        <button onclick="save();">Save</button>
        <a href="two.html">Next page</a>
        <script>
            function load() {
                var element = document.getElementById("loadedText");
                element.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("text");
            }

            function save() {
                var text = document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML;
                localStorage.setItem("text", text);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="loadedText"></p>
        <a href="one.html">Previous page</a>
        <script>
            var element = document.getElementById("loadedText");
            var text = localStorage.getItem("text");
            element.innerHTML = text;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```